# Is ZeroMQ with RT Linux (RT-PREEMPT patch) real time?

Tags: linux, real-time, zeromq

I am considering setting up ZeroMQ as message broker on a Linux kernel patched up with RT-PREEMPT (to make it real time).

Basically I want to publish/subscribe short events that are serialized using google protocol buffers.

```
1. Event Model Object (App #1) --->
2. Serialize Google protobuf ---> 
3. ZeroMQ ---> 
4. Deserialize Google protobuf --> 
5. Event Model object (App #2)
```

From #1 to #5 and perhaps back to #1, how will the real time guarantees of linux RT-PREEMPT be affected by ZeroMQ?

I am specifically looking for real time features of ZeroMQ. Does it provide such guarantees?

To put the question in perspective, lets say I want to know if ZeroMQ is worthy of deploying on time critical systems such as Ballistic Missile Defense or Boeing 777 autopilot.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly PREEMPT_RT reduces the maximum latency for a task but overall system throughput will be lower and the average latency probably higher.

Real time is a broad subject; to avoid confusion my definition of real time is in the order of tens of milliseconds per frame running at 30hz or higher.

> Does it provide such (real time features) guarantees?

As already answered no it does not and it it isn't what PREEMPT_RT is really about.

> Is ZeroMQ worthy of deploying on time critical systems?

Time critical is a loose definition; but a with a correctly designed protocol ZeroMQ is going to give you options in how messages are transported (memory, TCP, UDP / multicast) and rest assured that ZeroMQ does what it does really well.

IME ZeroMQ typically delivers fast on a local high speed network - but this will drop if you are using a wide network and this figure may raise as endpoints are added depending on which model you are using within ZeroMQ.

For real time systems it's not just about transmission speed, there is also latency and time synchronisation to consider.

It's worth reading the article [0MQ: Measuring messaging performance](http://zeromq.org/whitepapers:measuring-performance) - note that there is a high (1.5ms) latency at the start of message transmission that settles quickly - probably good if you are needing to transmit a lot of small messages at high frequency - not as good if you are transmitting a few larger messages at a lower rate.

[image: ZeroMQ latenecy]

> is ZeroMQ is worthy of deploying on time critical systems such as Ballistic Missile Defense or Boeing 777 autopilot.

It's important to understand the topology of what you're connecting and also how the latency will affect things and design a protocol accordingly.

So to take the case of the 777 autopilot - almost certainly yes ZeroMQ would be suitable simply because there is a lot of inertia in a stable aircraft so the airframe will take time to respond and the cleverness is inside the autopilot and not so much reliant on incoming sensor data at a high rate. On a 777 there is an Arinc 429 bus connecting the avionics and this runs at a maximum 100kbit/s between the limited number of endpoints that can be on any given bus.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q: *Does it provide such*** (real time features) **guarantees?**

No, it does not and never tried to do so. The Zen-of-Zero guarantees one to either deliver a complete message-payload or none at all, which means, your R/T-level code has never a need to test for a damaged message integrity (once a message got delivered). Yet, it does not guarantee a delivery as a whole and the application domain is free to build any such additional service-layer atop the smart and ultimately performant ZeroMQ-layer.

ZeroMQ has been since its earliest days a smart, asynchronous, broker-less tool for designing any kind of almost linear-scalable [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) messaging, with low-profile resources' needs and having an excellent latency/performance envelope.

This said, anyone can build on this and design any add-on features, that match some target application-domain specific needs ( N+1 robustness, N+M failure-resilience, adaptive node-rediscovery, ... ), which are principally neither hard-coded, nor pre-wired into the minimum footprint for low latency, best scalable smart-messaging core-engine.

All designs, where the rules of the Zen-of-Zero, coded so wisely into the ZeroMQ core-engine, can safely match the defined hard-Real-Time limits for the RT/Execution needs of such Real-Time constrained System-under-Review, will enjoy the ZeroMQ and its many-protocol support for `inproc://`, `ipc://`, `tipc://`,  `tcp://`, `pgm://`, `epgm://`, `udp://`, `vmci://` and other wire-level protocols.

> **Q: *Is ZeroMQ worthy of deploying on time critical systems?***

That depends a lot on indeed many things.

I remember guys in days, when F-16 avionics simulated an onboard network, that used internally an isolated high-speed deterministic and rather low latency ( due to static packet/payload sizes ) of 155-Mbit/s+ ATM-fabric for this on-plane switching-network just to enjoy it's benefits right for the R/T-control-motivated needs, so technology always matches some set of needs-to-have. Given your R/T-system design criteria gets defined, anyone may confirm/deny a feasible/in-feasible tools to design towards such R/T-system goals.

Factors will go way beyond the just ZeroMQ smart-features:

- properties of your critical system
- external constraints ( sector specific authoritative regulations )
- Project's planning
- Project's external ecosystem of cooperating parties ( greenfield systems have it too )
- your Team's knowledge of ZeroMQ or absence of using it in distributed-systems' designs
- ...
- and last but not least - the ceilings for financing and for showing the RTO demonstrator live demo and roll-out for acceptance tests.

Good luck with your forthcoming BMD or any other MCS. ZeroMQ style of thinking, the Zen-of-Zero can help you in many aspects of doing right things right.